# How to compare two dates in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, sequelize.js

I have issue where using model query.

if I want to compare two dates for example, one found in database and other is today's date.

I wrote like this.

```
model.findAll({
where:{
  startDate:{
      [Op.gt]:now Date().toISOString(),
}
}
})

is this a good way to compare??
```

Comment: You should probably ask on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
const { Op } = require('sequelize'); // "npm i sequelize"
const moment = require('moment'); // "npm i moment"

model.findAll({
    where: {
        startDate: {
            // $gt: moment().toDate(), // Sequelize version < 5
            [Op.gt]: moment().toDate(), // Sequelize version 5
        }
    }
});
```